# How can we include Environment specific Property in CAS-overlay

Tags: java, properties, configuration, cas

Does anyone came across implementing CAS custom environment specific property file(i.e. application.pro). 
Can someone please point me to some good documentation or can provide some information for the same.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer we have application.properties we can name application-someName.properties and pass -D parameter in tomcat.